# When should we host WCF service in IIS and when should we host in a windows service?

Tags: windows, wcf, iis, service

I need to host my WCF service but I am unable to decide whether I should host it in IIS or a windows service?

What are the advantages, drawbacks, benefits of one over the other please?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIS under version 7 is out of the question for any serious hosting anyway....

As for IIS7+/WAS vs. self-hosting in a NT service:

- the IIS7/WAS setup will "load on demand", e.g. when your first request comes in, a `ServiceHost` will be created, then that service host creates the service class to handle the request. This is beneficial from a memory point of view (uses no memory for the ServiceHost if no requests come in), but it's a bit of an additional overhead on the first call when IIS first needs to spin up the service host
- NT Service allows you to pre-create the `ServiceHost` and open it so it's ready to handle requests right away; a bit more memory usage, but a bit more responsive, at least on "first calls"

Another benefit of self-hosting: you're 100% in charge of when the service host starts, pauses, stops, and so on. With IIS/WAS, you're at times at the mercy of IIS with its potential to recycle app pools at the worst possible moment......

Answer (score 2):

The main advantages of IIS is that it handles the lifetime of your service for you: activation, recycling...

Its main drawback if you don't have v7 is that without [WAS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734677.aspx) it can only host http based web services

The services need more care in case of fatal error... and then need to be installed whereas a web site can be copied to its web folder once it has been created

If your version of iis is >= 7, then I don't see a lot of interest in not using WAS as it supports all the wcf transports, others might have a different view though...